# Easily delete 5000 mails from a Microsfot Outlook Web Access Email Accout

Tags: email

I have an email account, thorugh Microsoft Outlook Web Access. I have more than 4000 mails and would like to delete all of them, but I only manage to open 1 page (there are 200 or more) and have to select individually all the emails I want to delete.

Is it there a fastest way to do this? Commandline, etC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might not be the quickest solution, but for selecting a mass number of checkboxes easily I use a nice greasemonkey script where you can shift+click select a bunch of checkboxes in a range. Unfortunately I've lost the original link, but I think [this](http://commons.oreilly.com/wiki/index.php/Greasemonkey_Hacks/Web_Forms#Select_Multiple_Checkboxes) script might do the job. Another one works by drawing a box, available [here](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/73700).

Answer (score 0):

In addition (or instead of) using Greasemonkey I recommend to download [iMacros for Firefox](http://www.iopus.com/imacros/firefox/) (a web browser macro recorder). While Greasemonkey is great for changing page content, iMacros is better for quicky and easy web automation: Start iMacros, open your web mail account and record a short script that does the deletion for one emai. Then run it in a loop 5000 times. Tip: From my experience when testing/automating complex websites with it, you might need to [tweak](http://wiki.imacros.net/FAQ#Q:_A_link_changes_every_time_I_visit_the_web_page_.28.22session_ID.22.29.2C_how_can_I_replay_the_macro_without_error.3F) the macro a bit after recording before it works. But once it works, it is amazing ;)

PS: The same approach is shown here for [deleting all facebook wall posts](http://www.cynthiaperla.com/facebook/460/how-to-delete-all-groups-and-wall-posts-from-facebook-using-imacros.html).